# Change library views across site collections

Tags: list-view, view

We have about 500 `managed` `document libraries` (SharePoint 2010) across multiple site collections. I would like to change the default `view` on all these libraries so that a number of the columns are hidden from the existing default view. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Normally you would write a PowerShell script for this kind of task

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this answer here:

[modifying exisiting ListView in sharepoint 2010 using powershell](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/72483/modifying-exisiting-listview-in-sharepoint-2010-using-powershell)

This is for a single list - but you could modify it to loop thru your lists and set the view.

If you need to create a view as well you can use something like below:

```
#Get destination site and list
$web = Get-SPWeb "http://portal/sites/testsite"
$list = $web.GetList(($web.ServerRelativeUrl.TrimEnd("/") + "/Shared Documents"))

$viewTitle = "Sort by modified date" #Title property
#Add the column names from the ViewField property to a string collection
$viewFields = New-Object System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection
$viewFields.Add("DocIcon") > $null
$viewFields.Add("LinkFilename") > $null
$viewFields.Add("Modified") > $null
$viewFields.Add("Editor") > $null
$viewFields.Add("FileSizeDisplay") > $null
#Query property
$viewQuery = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Modified' Ascending='FALSE'/></OrderBy>"
#RowLimit property
$viewRowLimit = 50
#Paged property
$viewPaged = $true
#DefaultView property
$viewDefaultView = $false

#Create the view in the destination list
$newview = $list.Views.Add($viewTitle, $viewFields, $viewQuery, $viewRowLimit, $viewPaged, $viewDefaultView)
Write-Host ("View '" + $newview.Title + "' created in list '" + $list.Title + "' on site " + $web.Url)
$web.Dispose()
```

I just snagged the above from here (which has additional examples):

http://get-spscripts.com/2012/02/managing-creating-and-deleting.html